# kendo mvc declare grid filters in a different class

Tags: model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui

here's a small block of grid filter code

```
.ForString(str => str
    .Clear()
    .Contains("Contains")
    .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
    .StartsWith("Starts with")
    .EndsWith("Ends with")
    .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
    .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
    .IsNull("Is null")
    .IsNotNull("Is not null")
)
```

str in this case is a `kendo.mvc.ui.fluent.stringoperationsbuilder`
since we have over 150 pages, i have come up with a way to set up most mvc grids in a separate file and have filters i that.  However we have maybe 10 grids that, due to heavy customization are done in javascript directly and the method also doesn't seem to work on pages we have set up to server-process vs client.  What i would like to do is have a class return this so i can use it and i don't have to make changes all over the project.  This same method could also be used to help us in many other places with other shared properties.  In my experiments i was getting problems with "can not implicitly convert to action<>" etc and i am not good enough at this to even understand that part.  Can someone give me a headstart?
more info:  i'm trying to do something like this:

```
me.something1
me.something2
me.forString(str => 
    str
      .name
      .date
      .age)
```

I either need to be able to somehow (in this simple example) pass in str all at once from a variable OR somehow replace the forstring part from a variable or function commonly located somewhere else.  I've tried a few different things, in the above str is a 
    kendo.mvc.ui.fluent.stringoperationsbuilder 
but the forstring part expects an action<> of that type and we've had zero luck making an object of that type.

Comment: Could you show us a concrete example of what you have tried? At the moment I do not understand what you are aiming for.

Comment: i'm trying to do something like this:

me.something1
me.something2
me.forString(str => str.name
                              str.date
                             str.age)
I either need to be able to somehow (in this simple example) pass in str all at once from a variable OR somehow replace the forstring part from a variable or function commonly located somewhere else.  I've tried a few different things, in the above str is a kendo.mvc.ui.fluent.stringoperationsbuilder but the forstring part expects an action<> of that type and we've had zero luck making an object of that type.